# Date function in Debian is IST, how do I change the default timezone of date, all the timezones are correct CEST

Tags: linux, debian, raspberry-pi, date, time-zone

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 without RTC.
I am using [pisignage](https://pisignage.com/), a signage solution for the Pi. It's viewing [a webpage](https://www.kisp.be/lokaal_bezetting_lijst/25) with a time.

The pi is showing the wrong time because the `date` command on the pi is default set to (IST). How do I change the default timezone for date in Debian from (IST) to (CEST) to solve this issue?

I tried everything I could find:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to Super User. "I tried everything" should not be in the question. If the statement is true then there is nothing left to try, we cannot help you, there is no point in asking. If the statement is false then you should clearly tell us what exactly you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change in .profile or in .bash_profile if this file exist:

export TZ='Asia/Kolkata'

into

export TZ='Europe/Brussels'

Or

Remove the line:
export TZ='Asia/Kolkata'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Before anything else, make sure the `Universal time:` line shows the correct [UTC time](https://time.is/UTC). If it's wrong, everything else will be wrong. If it's correct, proceed with adjusting timezones.

The `/etc/timezone` file actually doesn't matter much. Programs only look at the **`/etc/localtime`** file, which is either a copy of the actual *timezone data* file from /usr/share, or (preferably) a symlink to the data file. For example, if you're in the "Europe/Brussels" timezone, then /etc/localtime should look like this:

```
$ ls -l /etc/localtime
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 36 Jun 19  2017 /etc/localtime -> ../usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Brussels
```

If it doesn't look like that, try setting the timezone via timedatectl again:

```
# timedatectl set-timezone Europe/Brussels
```

Also, in addition to the global system timezone, programs look at your **`$TZ` environment variable**. Normally it should be unset, to have them use the system timezone. If it *is* set, make sure it's set to the correct timezone name (or unset it).

```
$ export TZ=Europe/Brussels; date
2022-04-21T14:20:42 CEST

$ export TZ=UTC; date
2022-04-21T12:20:45 UTC

$ unset TZ; date
2022-04-21T15:20:48 EEST
```

Comment: $ export TZ=Europe/Brussels; date, worked if I checked date, but after an reboot it is IST again. Also /etc/localtime is correct: pi@Holstraat95:~$ ls -l /etc/localtime
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 35 Apr 22 15:06 /etc/localtime -> /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Brussels.

Comment: Ok, in that case what do you have in $TZ immediately after a reboot?

Comment: After reboot: echo $TZ
Asia/Kolkata

Comment: Found something in .bash_profile: export TZ='Asia/Kolkata'

Comment: Right, so remove that line from your .bash_profile completely.

Comment: Thanks without your input I would not found it

Answer (score 0):

Timezone updates need a reboot to take effect.
If a reboot does not solve your problem, try the following:

1. Run

```bsh
sudo dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata
```

2. Check the current default time zone and the local time zone. If there is a disparity, the `tzdata` package needs to be reinstalled:

```bsh
sudo apt-get install tzdata
```

Sources: [UbuntuTime](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuTime), [ServerFault Answer](https://serverfault.com/a/788341/962800)

Comment: "Timezone updates need a reboot to take effect." – they do not. They are effective instantly.